# jQuery FullCalendar object doens't support property or method qtip

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

The jQuery FullCalendar plugin throws this qtip error in IE versions 10 and below causing it not show:

Object doesn't support property or method 'qtip'

Chrome, Firefox, and IE11 don't seem to throw this error in console. I've done several google searches that document this as a known issue but have not found a concrete solution.

It was suggested that older versions of IE may not fully load the library and to add a set timeout function to make it work but did not seem to help

I have include the following js file in my page in this order: jquery-1.9.1.js, fullcalendar.min.js, jquery.qtip.min.js and the necessary CSS files to include as well.

The error is thrown on the qtip function here:

```
var tooltip = $('<div/>').qtip({
            id: 'fullcalendar',
            prerender: true,
            content: {
                text: ' ',
                title: {
                    button: true
                }
            },
            position: {
                my: 'bottom center',
                at: 'top center',
                target: 'mouse',
                viewport: $('#fullcalendar'),
                adjust: {
                    mouse: false,
                    scroll: false
                }
            },
            show: false,
            hide: false,
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-plain qtip-shadow'
            }
        }).qtip('api');
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me loading the following scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fullcalendar/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/qtip/jquery.qtip.css" />

<script src="/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="/qtip/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
```

And configuring FullCalendar like this, adding [**qTip**](http://qtip2.com/options#global.defaults) inside the `eventRender`:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: { /* config */ },
        events: function ( start, end, timezone, callback ) { /* config */ },
        eventRender: function ( event, element ) 
        {
            element.qtip({ 
                content: {
                    text: event.title
                },
                position: {
                    target: 'mouse',
                    adjust: { 
                        x: 10, 
                        y: 10, 
                        mouse: false 
                    }
                }
             });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```